# what is the best approach to store values in html data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

If I want to store more than one values in html in one data-attribute then what is the approach to get it done, and how can I find these values using jQuery?

In following case, What is the best approach to store values? comma separated, space separated.

And if I wish to find the `<li>` tags which having `"Mango"` in data-fruit attribute, how can I find it without using for loops and if conditions?

`<ul class = "Fruits"><li data-fruit="Mango,Apple">Mango And Apple </li><li data-fruit="Mango,Strawberry"> Mango And Strawberry</li><li data-fruit="Apple,Strawberry"> Apple And Strawberry</li>
</ul>`

Comment: I am building one filter using jquery, in that at some of the sections there are more than one values for some attributes, I just want to apply filters on them. The queries like $(li[data-fruit="' + 'Mango' + '"]') are failing to give desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can persist data in array format, then you can use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to fetch it from element.

```js
$('.Fruits li').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('fruit').includes('Mango');
}).addClass('red')
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="Fruits">
  <li data-fruit="['Mango','Apple']">Mango And Apple </li>
  <li data-fruit="['Mango','Strawberry']"> Mango And Strawberry</li>
  <li data-fruit="['Apple','Strawberry']"> Apple And Strawberry</li>
</ul>
```

As an alternate, you can use CSV and while retrieving convert it to an array

```js
$('.Fruits li').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('fruit').replace(/ /g, '').split(',').includes('Mango');
}).addClass('red')
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="Fruits">
  <li data-fruit="Mango,Apple">Mango And Apple </li>
  <li data-fruit="Mango,Strawberry"> Mango And Strawberry</li>
  <li data-fruit="Apple,Strawberry"> Apple And Strawberry</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a string. The spec doesn't define any particular format for the data in the attribute, which is designed to be processed by site specific JavaScript.

Your JavaScript can `your_data_attribute_value.split(" ");` if you like.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/niteshgoyal27390/go6bn9ad/)

Comment: this will add several lines of code, which I dont want.